# How to develop GPS tracker app using Rhomobile

Tags: gps, tracking, rhomobile

i want to develop a Rhomobile app which uses GPS tracker. so can any one suggest me

any tutorials or documents which helps me to develop GPS Tracker on Rhomobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think that the Rhomobile Documentation on GeoLocation covers this quite well. You can find the GeoLocation documentation [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#geolocation) . They have also developed [this](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples/tree/master/app/GeoLocation) sample application which shows how geo location works with Rhomobile.